# How to detach a tag using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The code is:

```
<span><span class="rank_no">1</span>CONTENTS_HERE</span>
```

How can I get `CONTENTS_HERE`?

When I use `THE_STRING.find('span')`, the result shows `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<span><span class="rank_no">1</span>CONTENTS_HERE</span>')
>>> soup.find('span').span.next_sibling
u'CONTENTS_HERE'
```

Comment: The problem is actually, CONTENTS_HERE string consists of multibyte encoding(korean). When I use what you let me know, they say ; UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-5: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Hoon: That is your `print` call, not BeautifulSoup.

Comment: the original data that i tried to get is utf-8, by the way.

Comment: what can I do for my multibyte data? I inserted #-*- coding:utf-8 -*- on top of the file and didn't work at all.

Comment: @Hoon: BeautifulSoup decodes your UTF-8 to Unicode values. Any strings are returned from BeautifulSoup API calls as `unicode` objects. If you then try to save those values into a file or print them on a terminal or console or IDLE window, they need to be encoded again. It is that last step that fails.

Comment: @Hoon: `# coding: utf8` is only for **source file encoding**, used when reading the source code. It has nothing to do with what happens when the code itself runs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You forgot to mention the module that `bs4` uses to decode to Unicode! It's my favorite part of BeautifulSoup! `UnicodeDammit`

Comment: @adsmith: It's not really of any importance here. The OP is having trouble with **encoding** not decoding.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes yes yes, but any excuse to mention `UnicodeDammit` gets my blood pumping, dammit!

Comment: I'm confused, guys.
So, what I have to do is :
1) get data which is in utf-8(original string) using BS
2) encode to utf-8 because bs returns in unicode
3) print

am I right?

Comment: print str(CONTENTS_HERE).encode('utf-8') didn't work. The error message is UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-3: ordinal not in range(128). It seems an ascii problem.. any ideas?